# Different text-style in Gridview Header

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, styles

```
<Columns>
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bil. No." />
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="No. Lesen Rampaian Miscellaneous License No." />
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tarikh Mansuh Lesen Rampaian Expiry Date of Misc License" />
</Columns>
```

Hi, I have been trying to change the font in the English version of this Gridview header to Italic. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the style on the header template like so:

```
<HeaderStyle  Font-Italic=true />
```

insert this tag just above your columns.

**EDIT:** If I understand correctly you want to change the header styles of only one column to italic.

An easy way to do this is to go to the design view, click the smart tag on the gridview and choose "edit Columns". Choose the column you'd like to change and choose HeaderStyle > Font > Italic > True. What you get is something like this: (You do not need to change your column to a template field>

```
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bil. No." >
               <HeaderStyle  Font-Italic="true" />
        </asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: I think I asked the wrong question. How do I change the font-style  in the same header of the GridView :? 
When I change to Italic, both of the texts get changed to Italic >:[